# How to check array size in c++ avoiding empty spaces

Tags: c++, arrays

I am making a password program, when you input a password from a character array and i want to check if all the array spaces are used. If c++ auto fills empty brackets how can i evaluate?

Comment: What do you mean by "empty spaces"?

Comment: @MartinHeralecký example we have a char[10] but you only input 6 chars, how can i get that length?

Comment: Post the code here, where you are reading the input (password) from the user.

Comment: @MartinHeralecký a simple cin>>char dude

Comment: @MartinHeralecký the input is '123456' but the array shows this but with randomly generated characters also to complete the array

Comment: Characters in an uninitialized array are not randomly generated.

Comment: @Martin Heralekcý every time a execute a cin leaving the array empty it shows me different characters

Comment: That doesn't mean they're randomly generated.

Comment: @RediRamaj -- Programming requires exact details of what you're using which means show us real code, or better yet a [mcve].  It isn't as easy as saying "a simple cin >> char;"  A `char` holds a single character, not a string.  Second, you don't specify a type with `cin` -- you specify a variable, i.e. `std::string s; cin >> s;`.

Answer (score 2):

You should be using [`std::getline`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/string/basic_string/getline) to read a line as a `std::string` instead of reading into an array.
What happens when the user enters a password that's longer than your 10 characters? UB happens, and you don't want that.

```
std::string password;
std::getline(std::cin, password);
if (password.size() != 10) {
    // Take appropriate action.
}
```

Answer (score -2):

One method is to initialize the array with zeroes, fill it with password from the user and then look for the first zero in the array, which will tell you how many characters the user entered.

```
char password[10];
std::fill(password, sizeof(password), 0);
std::cin >> password;

size_t realEnteredPasswordLength = strlen(password);
```

Answer (score -2):

To check the number of characters read you can do the following:

```
  char c[10];
  std::cin >> c;
  std::cout << strlen(c);
```

You do not have to initialize the array to zeroes before using istream operator >>. An additional null character will be automatically appended at the end of the array. Keep in mind that this will only read the whole password if it does not contain any whitespace characters. To read the whole line, you can do this instead

```
   char c[10];
   std::cin.getline(c, 10);
   std::cout << strlen(c);
```

This will read at most 10 characters from the next line, including a null terminator, and store them in the array c. This has the added bonus of protecting you against buffer overflows.

If you don't specify a maximum length for the password and using a char array is not a requirement you need to adhere to, I would suggest using a std::string instead

```
   std::string s;
   getline(std::cin, s);
   std::cout << s.size();
```